# Get current file name with IDApython

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk, ida-plugin

I am running my IDA script on many files (batching), and i need to get the file name the script is running on within the script. the problem is i cannot find any API that does that.

the closest things i found was GetIdbDir(), which doesn't include the file name, also there seems to be a get_path function in ida_loader, but it expects a c type pointer, when i gave it a python string it failed.

Comment: You can use `get_input_file_path()` IDC function and then extract the file name from it. It's also available in IDAPython as `ida_nalt.get_input_file_path` [source](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/).

Comment: @bart1e yep that worked thanks, you can post  the answer so i can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_input_file_path()` IDC function and then extract the file name from it.

It's also available in IDAPython as `ida_nalt.get_input_file_path` ([source](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)).

Answer (score 2):

There are three functions exposed by `ida_nalt` and two of those aliased from `idc` module.

- `idc.get_root_filename` = `ida_nalt.get_root_filename`
  Returns the file name only (no leading path elements; [old name `idc.GetInputFile`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml))
- `idc.get_input_file_path` = `ida_nalt.get_input_file_path`
  Returns the full file path ([old name `idc.GetInputFilePath`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml))
  ida_nalt.get_input_file_path
- and separately `ida_nalt.dbg_get_input_path`

All of them return a `str` and take no arguments.

PS: didn't want to butcher the original answer.